# InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,21], In[1]: [128,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

the following is my code could please help me

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'gopi_cnn_training_data',
        target_size=(100, 100),
        batch_size=32)
    

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'gopi_cnn_test_data',
        target_size=(100,100),
        batch_size=32)


cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()


cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[100,100,3]))


cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))


cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))


cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
 
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

cnn.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 25)
```

i am getting the following error
InvalidArgumentError:  Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,21], In[1]: [128,1]
[[node MatMul (defined at C:\Users\THUMMAGO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_5318]

Function call stack:
distributed_function

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this issue by using binary class dataset.

For solution,
You may need to provide either correct activation function and loss function in your code as below:

```
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) #for binary classes
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

or define the `units=no_of_classes` in final layer of model and choose the appropriate activation function and loss function to implement the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related with the data shape and input shape of the model. The item at [0] represents your data shape, and the item at [1] represents the input_shape of the model. You need to adjust the input shape to match the data shape.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).